# How to clear the graph drawn inPySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pysimplegui

Is there a way to clear the graph in PySimpleGUI before redraw a new image? i notice the function **window["-GRAPH-"].draw_image()** is causing a serious memory leak when the program run for sometime, as it is trying to stack the picture on top of all drawn images.

Background:

> My app is trying to show a live feed from a webcam, meanwhile will also do some drawing (depending on mouse click) on top of the camera feed. In order to detect the mouse click event from the camera feed, im using sg.Graph to capture mouse position.

sample_app_display: [user label the box of object in a live camera feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clMkN.png)

Code Snippet:

```
sg.Graph(853, (0, 480), (853, 0), key="-GRAPH-", change_submits=True, drag_submits=False)

...

camera = my_opencv_library(device=0)
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=20)
    if event == "-GRAPH-":
        camera.update_coordinate(values["-GRAPH-"])

    # obtain live feed with runtime drawing (based on mouse click)
    frame = camera.get_frame()
    imgbytes = cv2.imencode(".png", frame)[1].tobytes()
    window["-GRAPH-"].draw_image(data=imgbytes, location=(0,0))
```

Comment: I guess the answer is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64598764/pysimple-gui-not-clearing-matplotlib-graph-canvas). I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @A_Tiny_Speck_In_Programming, it did solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Erase the Graph - Removes all figures previously "drawn" using the Graph methods

Erase all figures on `sg.Graph` by

```py
window['-GRAPH-'].erase()
```

> Remove from the Graph the figure represented by id.

Erase specified figure on `sg.Graph` by `ids`

```py
window['-GRAPH-'].delete_figure(ids)
```

The `ids` is given to you anytime you call a drawing primitive, like

```py
ids = window["-GRAPH-"].draw_image(data=imgbytes, location=(0,0))
```

Update code

```py
sg.Graph(853, (0, 480), (853, 0), key="-GRAPH-", change_submits=True, drag_submits=False)

...

camera = my_opencv_library(device=0)
ids = None
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=20)
    if event == "-GRAPH-":
        camera.update_coordinate(values["-GRAPH-"])

    # obtain live feed with runtime drawing (based on mouse click)
    frame = camera.get_frame()
    imgbytes = cv2.imencode(".png", frame)[1].tobytes()
    if ids is not None:
       window["-GRAPH-"].delete_figure(ids)
    ids = window["-GRAPH-"].draw_image(data=imgbytes, location=(0,0))
```